# Calculate $E[X]^2$ where $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n,p)$ with binomial coefficients expansion

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, expected-value

Calculation of $EX$ using the binomial expansion formula is easy:

\begin{align}
EX &= \sum_{x=0}^{n}x\frac{n!}{(n-x)!x!}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}\\& =  np \sum_{x=1}^{n}\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-x)!(x-1)!}p^{x-1}(1-p)^{n-x}\\& = np(p+(1-p))^{n-1}\\& = np
\end{align}

How do I calculate $EX^2$ using the binomial expansion formula?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing when trying to go through the summation for $EX^2$? Would you please explain so that the community could provide you with a good answer? (...the answer below gives all you need to knock this off)

Comment: Don't use the formula: you know the variance of $X$, so once you have $E[X]$ all you need to is add its square to the variance to obtain $E[X^2].$

Answer (score 1):

This is a common exercise many of the textbooks would provide. There is not much to tell here but the approach to ease the derivation is to use the fact that ${n\choose 
 x}=\frac nx \cdot\frac{n-1}{x-1}{{n-2}\choose{x-2}}$ and writing $x^2=x(x-1) +x$ to utilize the former. You only need to incorporate them in $\mathbb EX^2.$